# Firebase Dois foreach duplicando dados

Tags: javascript, firebase, foreach

Amigos, comecei a desenvolver usando Firebase a pouco tempo. Estou "empacado" em uma parte do desenvolvimento onde estou usando um foreach dentro de outro foreach que está duplicando de forma estranha os resultados. Quando vejo o resultado dentro do console.log retornar sem a duplicidade. Objetivo do código é gerar uma listagem de pessoas.

Estrutura:
coleção(ViagensConfirmadas)/documento(id)/coleção(Passageiros)/documento(id)/coleção(lista passageiros)

```js
//ler e carregar documento viagem para impressão relatorio
carregar = function(id){
 var qtd = 0;
 var content = '';
 content +="<tr>";
 var table = document.getElementById("ex-table");
firestore.collection("ViagensConfirmadas").where("IdViagem", "==", id).get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
      var val = doc.data();
      //inicio for para pegar os passageiros
firestore.collection("ViagensConfirmadas/"+doc.id+"/Passageiros").get().then(function(queryySnapshot) {
    queryySnapshot.forEach(function(docc) {
     var pass = docc.data();
     content += "<td>" + pass.Nome + "</td>";
     content += "<td>" + pass.CPF + "</td>";//cpf
     content += "<td>" + pass.RG + "</td>";//rg
     //fim for para pegar os passageiros
     content += "<td>" + val.Telefone + "</td>";
     content += "<td>" + val.Nome + "</td>";
     content += "<td>" + val.Origem + "</td>";
     content += "<td>" + val.Destino + "</td>";
     content += "</tr>";
     console.log(pass.Nome);//AQUI ESTOU TENTO O RETORNO SEM DUPLICIDADE
    });
    qtd = qtd + val.QuantidadePassageiros;
    document.getElementById("qtd").value = qtd;//AQUI RETORNAR O VALOR CORRETO
    var text = content;
    table.innerHTML += text
   });
  });
 });
}
```

Dentro da coleção ViagensConfirmadas tenho 3 documentos. Onde o resultado apresentado está sendo escrito da seguinte forma:

O primeiro documento registrado no banco(existe 3 passageiros nesse documento) está sendo escrito duas veze;

Depois escreve o segundo documento registrado no banco(existe 1 passageiro nesse documento);

Depois escreve o novamente o primeiro documento e o segundo, e por fim o terceiro documento registrado no banco(existe 3 passageiros nesse documento), como se fosse um segundo loop, já passando por todos os documentos.

Fica assim:

```html
Pass1 CPF identidade 00-00000-0000 Resp1 Origem Destino
Pass2 CPF identidade 00-00000-0000 Resp1 Origem Destino
Pass3 CPF identidade 00-00000-0000 Resp1 Origem Destino
Pass1 CPF identidade 00-00000-0000 Resp1 Origem Destino
Pass2 CPF identidade 00-00000-0000 Resp1 Origem Destino
Pass3 CPF identidade 00-00000-0000 Resp1 Origem Destino
Pass4 CPF identidade 00-00000-0000 Resp2 Origem Destino
Pass1 CPF identidade 00-00000-0000 Resp1 Origem Destino
Pass2 CPF identidade 00-00000-0000 Resp1 Origem Destino
Pass3 CPF identidade 00-00000-0000 Resp1 Origem Destino
Pass4 CPF identidade 00-00000-0000 Resp2 Origem Destino
Pass5 CPF identidade 00-00000-0000 Resp1 Origem Destino
Pass6 CPF identidade 00-00000-0000 Resp1 Origem Destino
Pass7 CPF identidade 00-00000-0000 Resp1 Origem Destino
```

Já estou buscando uma qualificação quanto ao Firebase, porém estou com prazo apertado para esse projeto. Por isso venha humildemente solicitar o apoio de todos vocês.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, o erro está acontece porque você não está limpando a variável `content` após atribuir da consulta.

Segue um exemplo de como deve ser corrigido

```
...
            table.innerHTML += text

            content = '';
          });
...
```

Porem como você está usando requisições assíncronas as requisições dentro do primeiro `forEach` vão sobrescrever os dados anteriores

Tomei a liberdade de refatorar seu código na intenção de você aplicar com mais clareza seu script.

```
/* eslint-disable */

var montaHTML = function(viagem, passageiro) {
  return `
  <tr>
    <td>${passageiro.Nome}</td>
    <td>${passageiro.CPF}</td>
    <td>${passageiro.RG}</td>
    <td>${viagem.Telefone}</td>
    <td>${viagem.Nome}</td>
    <td>${viagem.Origem}</td>
    <td>${viagem.Destino}</td>
  </tr>
  `
}

var carregar = function (id) {
  // carrega elementos
  var table = document.getElementById("ex-table");
  var qtd = document.getElementById("qtd");

  firestore
    .collection("ViagensConfirmadas")
    .where("IdViagem", "==", id)
    .get()
    .then(function(viagens) {

      viagens.forEach(function(doc) {
        var viagem = doc.data();

        qtd.value = (qtd.value || 0) + viagem.QuantidadePassageiros;

        firestore
          .collection(`ViagensConfirmadas/${doc.id}/Passageiros`)
          .get()
          .then(function(passageiros) {

            passageiros.forEach(function(doc) {
              var passageiro = doc.data();

              // monta HTML conforme as requisições vão carregando
              table.innerHTML = `${table.innerHTML}${montaHTML(viagem, passageiro)}`;
            })
          })

      })
    })
}
```

Comment: Lucas! Muito Obrigado pelo sua ajuda. Que Deus possa te abençoar, pela gentileza e humildade para se predispor a ajudar. Pelo tempo que tenho adicionei o "content = '';" ao código, porém vou estudar melhor sua sugestão apresentada na reformulação, para melhor o script.

Comment: Fico muito grato em ajudar, qualquer coisa estou a disposição